# What is Halver or halfer equation, in regards to Geology/maps I think?

Tags: google-maps

I heard some guys last week talking about the halver/halfer equation I think related to  Maps but wasn't sure what they were referring to...I tried googling but cant find anything for it either??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it have been the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) for calculating the great circle distance between two points, given their longitudes and latitudes?